# jQuery basic structure

Tags: jquery

i wanna understand what that line means:

```
var oViewport = { obj: $('.viewport', root) };
```

it's a line out of the plugin tinyscrollbar. Can someone explain the values of this line to   me? I really searched for an answer but didn't find one. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

It creates an object literal and assigns it to a variable named `oViewport`:

```
var oViewport = {}; //Empty object literal
```

The object has one property, named `obj`, whose value is a jQuery object:

```
var oViewport = { obj: $() }; //Property with jQuery object as value
```

The jQuery object finds all elements with class "viewport" that are descendants of whatever `root` is. `root` is the context for the selector:

```
$(".viewport", root); //Select all .viewport elements within root
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var oViewport = { obj: $('.viewport', root) };
```

In this code an object is being created using [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_literals) syntax (e.g. `{ key: value }`) and assigned to the new variable `oViewport`.

The object has one key or property, "`obj`", and its value is the result of the function named `$` when called with the arguments `'.viewport` and `root`.

Since this is jQuery, `$` is the main [jQuery selector function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), and in this instance it's selecting DOM elements with the CSS class "viewport", but only those which are children of the object `root` (called the "context," which probably is a DOM element itself).

The code above is roughly analogous to the below:

```
var selector         = '.viewport',
    selectedElements = $( selector, root ),
    oViewport        = new Object()  // equivalent to oViewport = {}
;

oViewport['obj'] = selectedElements; // equiv. to oViewport.obj = selectedElements;
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `oViewport` defined as object `{obj: ...}`; value of `obj` key inside this object is a Sizzle selector of `.viewport` in context of variable `root` (selects all DOM elements with `viewport` class inside `root` variable, which, usually, some DOM element too.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. $('.viewport', root) 
        => this finds all elements having class viewport with context as root.

2. { obj: $('.viewport', root) }; 
       => creating a object literal with "obj" as property 
                       and the elements objects found above as value.

3. var oViewport = { obj: $('.viewport', root) };   
            => assigning the created object literal to variable "oViewport".
```